# Event listener function executed when page is loaded but event not happening

Tags: javascript

I am new to Web development. This is my first question. Thanks in advance.
I am trying to use JS and PHP to create a simple login form. I found that in JS if I use `window.onload`, the event listener callback function gets executed without submitting the form. This seems quite illogical. JS link is added to the footer not the header.

Partial codes are below.

HTML

```
<div class="container justify-content-center" >
    <div class="ht-100"></div>

    <div class="d-flex">

        <div class="flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1"></div>        

        <div>           
            <form name="login_form" id="login_form">
            
            <div class="mb-3" style="width:400px">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
                
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3" style="width:400px">
                <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required>
                
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login-button" id="login-button">Login</button>

            <div class="mt-3">
            <a href="" class="" >Forgot your password?</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="register.php" class="" >Have not registered yet?</a>
            </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1"></div>        

    </div>
    
</div>
```

JS

```
function login_handler(){
    document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener("click", login()); 
    
    function login(){   
            
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('email', document.getElementById('email').value);
        data.append('password', document.getElementById('password').value);
        // alert(document.getElementById('password').value);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "login_handler.php",true);
        console.log("step1");

        xhr.onload = function (){

            console.log("step2");

            if(this.response == 'ok'){
                console.log("step3");
                
            
            }
            else{
                console.log("step4");
            }
        }
    xhr.send(data);  
    };
    };
    window.onload = function(){
    
        login_handler();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you add the listener, don’t do “login()”, just do “login”. The one you put will call the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. why would the bracket matter though? I though when there is no argument when you call a function, you still need to put down ().

Comment: You don’t want to actually _call_ the function right then and there, you want to tell the event listener _which_ function to call when that event happens.